# SqlException: Cannot open database "path\db.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, windows-services

I know that this question have been already asked many times but I looked through the answers and haven't found solution for my problem.

I've built a `Windows Service` in C# that connects to the database and fill it with data from some other source. I set `Account -> LocalSystem` for `ServiceProcessInstaller` and `StartType -> Automatic` for `ServiceInstaller`.

I use Entity Framework to generate .edmx from database, this is a connection string:

```
<add name="ConStringName"
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;
     provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
     attachdbfilename=&quot;somePath\MyDbName.mdf&quot;;
     integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;
     MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
     App=EntityFramework'"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

And I have this code:

```
var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
objContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM Properties;");
```

On the second line I get

```
Cannot open database "path\DbName.MDF" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
```

**What I've tried so far:**

**1)** tried this code for each database table:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON  dbo.TableName TO "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM";
```

and without dbo.

```
 GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON  TableName TO "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM";
```

**2)** I have set the permissions for this user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' in my database:
In SSMS: Databases => myDatabase -> Security -> Users -> 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' -> Properties -> Membership -> db_owner

**3)** Tried to set perissions for this account in SQL Server: 
Databases -> Security -> Logins -> 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' -> Properties -> set db_owner here

**The weird thing:**
One time I have restarted the computer and everything was working!! Like this LocalSystem had permissions and the Windows Service could access the database and perform all the operations!

But than after some circumstances this exception started to appear again. I've tried to restart the computer but failed.

I know I'm missing something obvious. Please, help me find this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then trying to set permission to your database to local system account, it's better to do one of the following:

1. Change the account that runs the windows service to a Windows account that already have a permission in the database.
2. Don't use `integrated security=True` in your connection string but specify a `User Id` and `Password`.

Comment: Hi! For the second option should I create a windows based or sql server based user?

Comment: I've created a new sql server-based user but for some reason when I'm trying to connect to the database with the specified userName and password from the visual studio's server explorer I get: "The attempt to attach to the db file failed with the following info: Login failed for user test_user". I have enterprise edition of sql server, maybe that somehow relates to the problem

Comment: And even if I use my windows creadentials in connection string: User Id=windowsUserName; Password=windowsPassword; (integrated security removed) I get the same SqlException

Comment: Have you tried that in SQL Server  management studio. Obviously you need a valid username and password first. There's something wrong with your setup but it's hard for me to know what. Once you have you user set up, you can put it into connection string.

Comment: what I do: Security -> Logins -> New Login -> enter name and password (for example "123") -> pick default database -> map users -> select my db and choose db_owner. Then I open this new user properties and see that the password is 15 characters long!!! I specified "123". ???

Comment: It always shows it like that so that other people can't learn the length of password. That's for security.

Comment: I think I just unable to log in with sql server authentication. I've set "SQL Server And Windows Authentication mode" and restarted the server instance but I'm still unable to login.

Comment: Once you set up any login, just put it in the connection string. If you have problems with setting up the login, maybe ask a separate question. SO should have one problem per question.